# Bandwidth: "rejected-unallocated-from-number"

Tags: sms

Trying the Banwidth API:

```
$ curl -X POST 'https://messaging.bandwidth.com/api/v2/users/123/messages' \
-H 'Authorization: Basic bW_F00bar' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \ 
-d '{"to":["+8162807777"],"from":"+4096557777", \
"text":"Doloret amet","applicationId":"1c1dfad515d", "tag": "Try 19"}'}
```

I'm getting:

```
"description"=>"rejected-unallocated-from-number", error: 4405
```

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to add the country code to the numbers. Modify this:

```
"to":["+8162807777"],"from":"+4096557777"
```

to:

```
"to":["+18162807777"],"from":"+14096557777"
```